# Enable xdebug on Lando using Pantheon recipe and PHPStorm

Tags: virtual-machine, 8, debugging

I am trying to enable xdebug on Lando using the pantheon recipe.
I have tried different tutorials, but PHPStorm does not seem to connect to Lando, or xdebug is not correctly enabled on Lando.

```
recipe: pantheon
config:
  framework: drupal8
  xdebug: true
```

Have some of you had this issue?

Comment: This question probably needs to go to the lando issue queue or Stack Overflow.  Setting up the xdebug connection between PHPStorm and Lando is a PHP issue and isn't specific to Drupal. That said, the absolute requirement for getting xdebug working with PHPStorm in Lando is to make sure you have set the lando docker container PHP as the CLI interpreter in the PHPStorm settings.  From there, it's a bit of trial-and-error and depends on the versions of lando, PHP, and PHPStorm.

Comment: I am able to setup xdebug on a Lando environemnt, the problem is when I am using the pantheon recipe for Drupal.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @no-sssweat works great. Even so, many of those settings can be removed, and you can set up tooling so xdebug isn't always running (and slowing down your local testing). This is based on the lando github issue ["Allow faster xdebug on/off toggling"](https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1668#issuecomment-772829423):

**.lando.yml**

```
recipe: pantheon
config:
  framework: drupal8
  xdebug: off
  config:
    php: .lando.php.ini
services:
  appserver:
    overrides:
      environment:
        XDEBUG_MODE:
tooling:
  xdebug-on:
    service: appserver
    description: Enable xdebug for nginx
    cmd:
      - echo "[INFO] Enabling xdebug ..."
      - echo xdebug.mode = "debug,develop" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-lando-xdebug.ini
      - pkill -o -USR2 php-fpm
    user: root
  xdebug-off:
    service: appserver
    description: Disable xdebug for nginx
    cmd:
      - echo "[INFO] Disabling xdebug ..."
      - echo xdebug.mode = "off" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-lando-xdebug.ini
      - pkill -o -USR2 php-fpm
    user: root
```

(yes, you need XDEBUG_MODE in there so that you can override the value, and yes, start with it off so that it doesn't enable debugging by default)

**.lando.php.ini**

```
; Xdebug settings required for PhpStorm.
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Then leave PhpStorm listening all the time and just run the tooling:

```sh
>lando xdebug-on
>lando xdebug-off
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing! I will certainly add this to the tooling so I don't have to rebuild every time to turn on and off and update the overrides environment as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the boost! It was your answer that helped me get this in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** While my answer works, @Eric Woods [answer is superior](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/315971/27710).

---

Ever since Xdebug 3 came out, I've had to use a .lando.php.ini file in order for it to work with Lando.

```
recipe: pantheon
config:
  framework: drupal8
services:
  appserver:
    type: php
    xdebug: true
    config:
      php: .lando.php.ini
    overrides:
      environment:
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=appserver"
        LANDO_HOST_IP: "host.docker.internal"
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=host.docker.internal"
```

In the project's root folder, create a .lando.php.ini

**.lando.php.ini**

```
; Xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.client_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

In your PHP storm settings, create the "appserver" by hitting the "+" icon. Make sure you add the `/app` path to the root.

[image]

<sub>**Note:** Replace Host with your actual host name.</sub>